# Cannot create a neutral unit with a trigger

Tags: modding, map-editor, starcraft

I've been playing around with the starcraft UMS (Use map settings) for a while and usually i figure things out pretty quickly when im stuck. Alas not this time.

I'm trying to place a neutral unit (player 12) using a trigger. It refuses to work. 
I'm using Scmdraft 2.0 as my editor (but i cant get it to work in other editors either)
(all neutral units placed before the game starts are visible and all other triggers work fine. Also i created a text msg and it does displays it in-game so the trigger triggers )

For testing I created a trigger that looks like this:

```
Player: neutral (i tried neutral players player 1 and all players as well)
Condition: 
-always
Action:
-Create *1 Terran Medic* at '*location 022*' for *Neutral* (also tried neutral players)
```

When I start the game nothing happens.

Here is what I tried:

1. I tried placing a start location for neutral player (player 12)
2. I tried changing the owner under map properties of player 12 to neutral and computer from unused which was the default.

Although it seems like it should be a common enough problem, I don't see it in any FAQ and I cant find anything about it when I Google it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure this falls in the Game Mod and Development catergory. Definitely try GameDev.SE.

Comment: I managed to make my trigger work by turning player number 7 to a rescuable player. I wish i could keep player number seven as a human player. and rescuable is not really an neutral player either :/

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite a while since I've messed around with the SC:BW editor, but my initial thought here is that triggers aren't run for Neutral players. Try putting the trigger under Player 1 and creating the unit for Player 12.

Then just make sure you have a start location for Player 1 and that he isn't immediately losing the game and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sadly, I did try it with player one (as my question states) Does doing what you described worked for you ??

Comment: You said you ran it with Player 1, but you didn't say that you tried to create the unit for P12 in the Actions.

Comment: P12 doesnt appear in my trigger list. Whats stranger is that i can kill units owned by neutral (if i place them with the editor) but i cannot create units for neutral or give units to neutral.

Comment: btw you should get a badge for migrating here to answer my question.

Comment: Maybe if my solution worked. -.- I don't have SC:BW installed anymore, otherwise I'd figure it out. I recommend posting on staredit.net though, they'll have people far better than I.

Comment: @Xitcod13 Are you using the default map editor, or have you downloaded an improved custom map editor?  IIRC, it is only the custom map editors which can use players 9 - 12 in triggers.